# How can i show an asterisk (to indicate field is required) inside a select2 dropdown?

Tags: php, jquery, css, codeigniter, jquery-select2

I have a form where I need a multiselect. For that I use Select2.
Problem is: In this form all of my fields are required, and I inform my users about that by showing an asterisk when the field is empty. However, Select2 totally ignores the fact there is a required attribute on the created select.

So my question is: How can i show an asterisk image inside a select2 dropdown? Preferably with the same method i use for my other inputs?

EDIT: I already took care of the validation part. My question is purely about informing the user what fields are required.

**Example Form**

[image: form with asterisk to show required fields]

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" placeholder="" maxlength="255" style="width: 300px" required="required"/>
<input type="text" name="label" id="label" value="" maxlength="8" style="width: 150px" required="required"/>
<?php
echo form_multiselect('client_types[]', $client_types, set_array('client_types', null), 'class="select2" style="width: 315px;" required="required"');
?>
```

**CSS**

```
input:required, textarea:required {
    background: #fff url(../images/red_asterisk.png) no-repeat 98% center;
}

.required_notification {
    color:#d45252;
    margin:5px 0 0 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

input:required:valid, textarea:required:valid {
    background: #fff url(../images/valid.png) no-repeat 98% center;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #5cd053;
    border-color: #28921f;
}
input:focus:invalid, textarea:focus:invalid {
    background: #fff url(../images/invalid.png) no-repeat 98% center;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #d45252;
    border-color: #b03535
}
```

Comment: Just curious why are you using an image for an asterisk?

Comment: It seemed the best way to go back then

Answer (score 1):

You can do three things:

1) Create a rule in Select 2 and copy the multiple rule. That rule adds the little x in that position so you can replace with an asterisk instead for yours. This is most likely the least preferable of the three options so I won't go into details.

2) You can use CSS on your select2 container like:

```
select2-container:after {
  content: "*";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 5px;
  color: red;
}
select2-container { position: relative; }
```

Not exact code but you get my drift. If this is for specific fields you might have to add a class to that field and reflect that in your CSS or add a wrapper element around your select and target that as well.

3) If compatibility is an issue you could always use jQuery.

```
$(".select2-container").append("<span class="asterisk">*</span>");
```

Again using your selectors to get the exact element you want and add CSS for the asterisk span.

I don't know enough about select2 so if there's an option in the init for adding a required indicator that's going to be your best best so I would start researching there to see if this is something provided out of the box and if not then you can try one of the above options.

Answer (score -1):

I had same problem. And i found out 2 acceptable (for me) solutions.

1. Use ajax to validate field is it unset\set incorrectly.
2. Use simple JavaScript to validate is there any information in the input.

   It can be done when clicking the button (submit) or after change focus from input.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I guess my question was probably a bit off, but i want to show the asterisk inside the Select2, so it looks the same as my other inputs. I have already taken care of the validation part, but i only need to inform the user about required fields before he posts his data

Comment: i answer exactly at your question.You want to make your custom required fields notification .So  put asterisk image at all your required inputs and validate by js is there any text inside, if yes remove image.